# Rank of the element-wise square of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I am looking for a real matrix A of rank r with non-negative entries with the following property :

For every complex matrix B such that $B\circ \overline B=A$, the rank of B is strictly greater than r.

Here what I denote $B\circ \overline B$ is the matrix with entries equal to the square of the absolute value of the entries of $B$ (element-wise operations). In the case of real matrices, this would be the square element-wise of $B$, denoted $B^{\circ 2}$.

---

I solve below the case where B is restricted to be a real matrix , but would be interested in solving the problem where B can be a complex matrix, or showing that it has no solution.

Consider $A=\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right),$ it is clear that $A$ has rank 2. 
Now consider all real matrices B such that $A=B^{\circ 2}$, these matrices can be written, up to arbitrary signs on each entries, as
$B=\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{2} & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right),$ and these matrices all have rank 3, which solves the problem.

However if we allow B to be a complex matrix, there are infinitely many matrices such that $B\circ \overline B=A$, since the previous matrix elements can have any phase.
In particular $B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1+i & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
i & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right)$ is such a matrix with rank 2, so the property doesn't hold for $A$.

Comment: As it's written, your $A \neq B^{\circ 2}$, and $A$ is invertible.

Comment: I think he means $A = [[2 1 1], [1 0 1], [1 1 0]]$ instead

Comment: @MoonKnight I think you're right.  For a minute I was calculating that $B^{\circ 2}$ was invertible, but I had it wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, thanks for noticing it, it is now fixed.